# Using jQuery 1.4.4 This simple method fails for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.get($(this).attr('rel'), function(response){}, 'script')
.error(function(){ alert('this failed')});
```

I get. `.error is not a method` . But it was added in version 1.4.3

http://api.jquery.com/error/

Is there some kind of type I have ?

Comment: Any particular reason you're still using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: Oh now I'm embaressed. It's a legacy app. That is convoluted and huge.

Comment: I don't think an answer that is not listing the alternatives is a correct answer. There are workarounds around this. You *need to* "bind it to something else" indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `$.get` in jQuery 1.4.3 does not have a `.error` method.  I am actually not sure what the return value is, but you should be able to check it .. whatever it is, it doesn't have `.error`.  You will have to bind it to something else.

At some point, jQuery started returning jqxhr objects from `$.get`, `$.post`, `$.ajax`, etc.  I believe this is after 1.5 when they introduced `Deferred`, but I'm not 100% sure.  The jqxhr object has `.done`, `.fail` and `.always` (implementing `Deferred`), so you would be able to do `$.get().fail()` at some point after jQuery 1.5.  You definitely can in jQuery 1.7.

Either upgrade jQuery or use `$.ajax` instead with `error` as a setting.

Comment: Ah. I figured this would happen. I think this is the way out of the jungle. Many thanks Tandu~